# How to add space in inspector in nested object to a field(property) with PropertyAttribute

Tags: unity, gui

I use `GUILayout.Space(px)` to add space after some property. Property is drawn using `PropertyDrawer` via `PropertyAttribute`.

[image: Inspector Window]

You can see that `Min Max Prop` displays properly inside `targetObject`(AudioPlayer) but if it's in nested object like `Engine, Engine Multi, Filed` it adds space to the `targetObject` not the nested object itself.

Comment: sharing the code might help us get on the right track and fix the problem.

Comment: @UriPopov can't do that right now. https://pastebin.com/KkUPyYu6 - the same principle to how that is done. `HideInDerivedAttribute` simply empty class that inherits `PropertyAttribute`. The problem is not in my code but in Unity API. It should target nested object, instead, it targets object at the top of the hierarchy. I'm looking for some workaround. If I get home, maybe I will be able to post related code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in nested objects by adding height to overridden `GetPropertyHeight()` of `PropertyDrawer`.

[image: Solution]

```
namespace Kimo.Assistance.UTILITY
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(MultiSupportPropertyAttribute))]
    [CanEditMultipleObjects]
    public class MultiSupportPropertyAttributeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        private MultiSupportPropertyAttribute _attribute;

        public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            if (this._attribute == null)
                this._attribute = this.attribute as MultiSupportPropertyAttribute;

            return base.GetPropertyHeight(property, label) + this._attribute.GetPropertyExtensionHeight();
        }

        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            //foreach (var attribute in fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false))
            //{
            //  (attribute as MultiSupportPropertyAttribute).DrawInInspector(position, property, label);
            //}

            this._attribute.BeginDrawInInspector(position, property, label);
            this._attribute.DrawInInspector(position, property, label);
            this._attribute.EndDrawInInspector(position, property, label);
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

`GetPropertyExtensionHeight()` - is my method that needs to be overridden. It just adds some space instead of giving a full new space size.

[image: Usage example]

```
public override float GetPropertyExtensionHeight()
{
    if (this._compactFormat)
        return InspectorUtility.DEFAULT_FIELD_HEIGHT;
    return 0;
}
```

Works like a charm:

[image: Working example]